how tagging index in rst file
I have a file structure that I want to publish docomentation to confluence using sphinx. But there is a problem, I don't understand how to add a link to the main page
structure
Home page
========================

Navigation
========================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3
   
   index
   first
   second
   third
   anything


What tags do I need to add in order for sphinx to automatically generate a link to the index
conf.py structure
extensions = [
    'sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder',
]

confluence_publish = True
confluence_space_key = 'username'

confluence_server_url = 'confluence.server.com'
confluence_page_hierarchy = True
confluence_page_generation_notice = True
confluence_prev_next_buttons_location = 'top'
confluence_server_user = 'username'
confluence_server_pass = 'password'

